# How to merge 2 objects in Laravel and Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Im try to create a simple CRUD App in Laravel + Vue.JS (Vuex also)
And I have small problem
What is the problem actually
I have a table 'categories'
Structure of this table u can see on screenshot

[image]
And i have created 2 test rows
u can see on screenshot
How can I insert a title instead of a value parent_id
If parent_id has value like someone ids
Im try v-for in Vue Componetn and v-if
But i dont have any results
This is my code:

```
 <tr v-for="(category, $index) in categories" :key="category.id">
                                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                        <td>{{category.title}}</td>
                                        <td v-if="category.parent_id === null">Category</td>
                                        <td v-else>SubCategory</td>
                                        <td>{{category.created_at | moment("DD, MMMM, YYYY")}}</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
```

[image]

This is my data what im get from Controller

[image]

Anyway thanks for help

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, You want to show parents title instead of parent_id ?

Comment: Yes 
As u have some information it will be nice

Answer (score 0):

Solution will be to define relation hasOne like

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class,'id','parent_id');
}
```

And then you can define resource, where you can claim parent's title using defined relation like below

```
$this->parent->title
```

Create you resource using command

```
php artisan make:resource CategoryResource
```

Then in your controller you should use resource

```
use App\Http\Resources\CategoryResource;
```

and within controller's action provide response like

```
$categories = Category::paginate(15);
return CategoryResource::collection($results); // instead of response()->json($categories , 200);
```

And example how your resource should look like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CategoryResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
            'parent_title' => $this->parent->title,
             ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Info about resources you can find https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: Not sure, what exactly didn't work for you? Please be more specific. for example show code snippet, how you're sending response to front from your controller.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТимченко Maybe I wan't so clear. The link that I sent you, there were described how to create an resource.
Try using command `php artisan make:resource `CategoryResource` and manage your response from there.
You should check path `app\Http\Resources`.
I will update my answer with code snippet from resources

Comment: I'm talking about response from backend. I you will get fixed it, it will be easy to loop throw

Answer (score 0):

This is code of controller

```
public function index()
{
    $result = ['success' => true];

    $category = Category::paginate(15);
    $result['category'] = $category->items();
    $result['pagination']['currentPage'] = $category->currentPage();
    $result['pagination']['total'] = $category->total();
    $result['pagination']['perPage'] = $category->perPage();
    return response()->json($result, 200);
}
```

And here is how I want it to be
[image]

I think render function adn array processing must be at the Vue Component

This is my Category model code

```
 public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App/Products');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class,'id','parent_id');
}
```